# How to add an Facebook Like button that does not show how poorly your site is liked?

Tags: facebook

I've added an Facebook Like button, but as my site is still very small I believe it is not a good idea to show that bubble-box telling everyone that this page only has 3 likes. Then, it's better visitors don't see how bad it performs so they're not blended and can decide on their own if it's cool or not.

This is how I've added that button:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://mywebsite.com" layout="button_count" colorscheme="dark"></fb:like>
```

Any way to tell it that it should not yell out that almost nobody likes it? It sucks to see that every day on the website! ;)

Comment: It would probably be more profitable to not worry about things that are easy to do (click "like") and don't mean so much, and worry about making your site more valuable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to not have it included, but you can probably just set the CSS to display:none for the div with the count in it. I think it might be connect_confirmation_cell_no_like.

```
#connect_confirmation_cell_no_like {
    display: none;
}
```

although it will still be in the markup if they check the elements of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Remove it :)

Or make a facebook page for your website and use the addLike() function in the FB API to like that Facebook Page rather than your page. It's up to you then to show number of likes or not.

Or, develop your own "Like" system and don't rely on FB at all.